# how to access rownames in a chained data.table of R

Tags: r, data.table

We need rownames sometimes to create a new column that is a function of previous columns but aggregated just for one row (each row). In other words the function is operating across the row.

Consider this:

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)

dt <- data.table(lon=77+rnorm(100),lat=13 + rnorm(100),i.lon=77+rnorm(100),i.lat=13 + rnorm(100))
dt[,dist:=distGeo(p1=c(lon,lat),p2=c(i.lon,i.lat)),by=rownames(dt)] # correct
```

The second line of code works fine as the data.table name `dt` is available inside the square brackets (which in itself does not look quite elegant to me), but not always.

What if there is a chain of data.tables? Consider this extension of previous example:

```
dt[lon>77 & lat<12.5][,dist:=distGeo(p1=c(lon,lat),p2=c(i.lon,i.lat)),by=rownames(dt)] # incorrect
```

Clearly this is an incorrect use as `rownames(dt)` is a different length than the subsetted data.table passed inside to the next in chain.

I guess my larger question is: Is `rownames()` the only way to achieve summarisation on each row? If not then the specific question remains: how do we access the data.table inside the `by=` construct if it is a chained data.table?

Comment: Data.table does not use rownames. It is more efficient to store it as a column (call it row.names) and use this in the chain.

Comment: Aren't operations in data.table already rowwise? If I use sum function I will get the sum for each row. I don't understand why is it needed to group by row in this case... Maybe to force the input of distGeo not to be a vector...

Comment: @daniellga: not exactly, functions like `paste(..collapse=)` , or the humble `sum` are vectorised and all the rows are considered at once.

Comment: @LazarusThurston what I meant is that, although it's vectorized, the operation is done like it's rowise. I think the only solution you had in this question is the way to go. Instead of grouping rowwise in a data.table operation, it's probably faster and more readable to fix the function you are applying to accept to work in a vectorized way.

Comment: Or even going for a for loop, there's no problem in doing that.

Comment: This seems like before the data got here, there was a join step. You might be able to do this aggregation on the join with ```by = .EACHI```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cbind`:

```
dt <- data.table(lon=77+rnorm(100),lat=13 + rnorm(100),i.lon=77+rnorm(100),i.lat=13 + rnorm(100))
dt[,dist:=distGeo(p1=cbind(lon,lat),p2=cbind(i.lon,i.lat))]
# correct : 100 lines
dt[lon>77 & lat<12.5][,dist:=distGeo(p1=cbind(lon,lat),p2=cbind(i.lon,i.lat))]
# also correct : 16 lines
```

`:=` works on each row without need for summarization.
`cbind` allows to supply the expexted n*2 lat-lon matrix to the function.

Comment: your solution may work but looks highly verbose. I was looking for a more elegant or crisper solution: something like `by=.I`(but this does not work). However I think I will go by the earlier suggestion of creating `rown=rownames()` in the original DT and then downstream using `by=rown`.

Comment: If `cbind` works it means the function `distGeo` does indeed accept a vector. I will try this out soon and accept the answer.